# How to map @OneToMany field into List<DTO> when using JPQL or HQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class CityExpert {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cityExpert")
    private List<CityExpertDocument> documents;

    // Lots of other fields...
}

@Entity
public class CityExpertDocument {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private CityExpert cityExpert;

    // Lots of other fields...
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    // Lots of other fields...
}
```

I have the following HQL query, in which I select a subset of `CityExpert`s:

```
"select " +
        "e " +
"from " +
        "CityExpert e " +
"where " +
        "( (lower(e.user.name) like concat('%', lower(?1), '%') or e.user.name is null) or ?1 = '' ) " +
        "and " +
        "( (lower(e.user.phone) like concat('%', lower(?2), '%') or e.user.phone is null) or ?2 = '' ) "
```

However, since there are too many fields in `CityExpert`, I don't want to select all fields. Hence, I have changed the query as follows:

```
"select " +
        "e.user.name, " +
        "e.user.email, " +
        "e.documents " +
"from " +
        "CityExpert e " +
"where " +
        "( (lower(e.user.name) like concat('%', lower(?1), '%') or e.user.name is null) or ?1 = '' ) " +
        "and " +
        "( (lower(e.user.phone) like concat('%', lower(?2), '%') or e.user.phone is null) or ?2 = '' ) "
```

However, apparently we cannot select a one-to-many field in an entity like that, because I am getting a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` with the preceding query (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474370/hibernate-onetomany-throws-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-you-have-an-error-in-your)). Hence, I have changed the query to following:

```
"select " +
        "e.user.name, " +
        "e.user.email, " +
        "d " +
"from " +
        "CityExpert e " +
        "left join " +
        "e.documents d" +
"where " +
        "( (lower(e.user.name) like concat('%', lower(?1), '%') or e.user.name is null) or ?1 = '' ) " +
        "and " +
        "( (lower(e.user.phone) like concat('%', lower(?2), '%') or e.user.phone is null) or ?2 = '' ) "
```

However, this time the result becomes a `List<Object[]>`, instead of `List<CityExpert>`.

I have created the following DTO:

```
public class CityExpertDTO {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<CityExpertDocument> documents;

}
```

However, I don't know how I should map the result returned by Hibernate to `List<CityExpertDTO>`. I mean, I can do this manually but surely there must be an automated solution provided by Hibernate.

I am using Spring Data JPA and using the HQL as follows:

```
public interface CityExpertRepository extends JpaRepository<CityExpert, Long> {

    @Query(
            "select " +
                    "e " +
            "from " +
                    "CityExpert e " +
            "where " +
                    "( (lower(e.user.name) like concat('%', lower(?1), '%') or e.user.name is null) or ?1 = '' ) " +
                    "and " +
                    "( (lower(e.user.phone) like concat('%', lower(?2), '%') or e.user.phone is null) or ?2 = '' ) "
    )
    Set<CityExpert> findUsingNameAndPhoneNumber(String name,
                                                String phoneNumber);

}
```

How can I map the result to `CityExpertDTO`?

Comment: I think you can not directly map entry into dto I had same problem and I just create native query and selected all datas and casted via for loop !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Table relationships

Assuming we have the following `post` and `post_comment` tables, which form a one-to-many relationship via the `post_id` Foreign Key column in the `post_comment` table.

[image: The post and post_comment tables used for the JPA DTO projection]

### SQL Projection

Considering we have a use case that only requires fetching the `id` and `title` columns from the `post` table, as well as the `id` and `review` columns from the `post_comment` tables, we could use the following JPQL query to fetch the required projection:

```
select p.id as p_id, 
       p.title as p_title,
       pc.id as pc_id, 
       pc.review as pc_review
from PostComment pc
join pc.post p
order by pc.id
```

When running the projection query above, we get the following results:

```
| p.id | p.title                           | pc.id | pc.review                             |
|------|-----------------------------------|-------|---------------------------------------|
| 1    | High-Performance Java Persistence | 1     | Best book on JPA and Hibernate!       |
| 1    | High-Performance Java Persistence | 2     | A must-read for every Java developer! |
| 2    | Hypersistence Optimizer           | 3     | It's like pair programming with Vlad! |
```

### DTO Projection

However, we don't want to use a tabular-based `ResultSet` or the default `List<Object[]>`JPA or Hibernate query projection. We want to transform the aforementioned query result set to a `List` of `PostDTO` objects, each such object having a `comments` collection containing all the associated `PostCommentDTO` objects:

[image: The PostDTO and PostCommentDTO used for DTO projection]

We can use a Hibernate [`ResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/), as illustrated by the following example:

```
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p.id as p_id, 
           p.title as p_title,
           pc.id as pc_id, 
           pc.review as pc_review
    from PostComment pc
    join pc.post p
    order by pc.id
    """)
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setResultTransformer(new PostDTOResultTransformer())
.getResultList();

assertEquals(2, postDTOs.size());
assertEquals(2, postDTOs.get(0).getComments().size());
assertEquals(1, postDTOs.get(1).getComments().size());
```

The `PostDTOResultTransformer` is going to define the mapping between the `Object[]` projection and the `PostDTO` object containing the `PostCommentDTO` child DTO objects:

```
public class PostDTOResultTransformer 
        implements ResultTransformer {

    private Map<Long, PostDTO> postDTOMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(
            Object[] tuple, 
            String[] aliases) {
            
        Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap = aliasToIndexMap(aliases);
        
        Long postId = longValue(tuple[aliasToIndexMap.get(PostDTO.ID_ALIAS)]);

        PostDTO postDTO = postDTOMap.computeIfAbsent(
            postId, 
            id -> new PostDTO(tuple, aliasToIndexMap)
        );
        
        postDTO.getComments().add(
            new PostCommentDTO(tuple, aliasToIndexMap)
        );

        return postDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) {
        return new ArrayList<>(postDTOMap.values());
    }
}
```

The `aliasToIndexMap` is just a small utility that allows us to build a `Map` structure that associates the column aliases and the index where the column value is located in the `Object[]` `tuple` array:

```
public  Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap(
        String[] aliases) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
        aliasToIndexMap.put(aliases[i], i);
    }
    
    return aliasToIndexMap;
}
```

The `postDTOMap` is where we are going to store all `PostDTO` entities that, in the end, will be returned by the query execution. The reason we are using the `postDTOMap` is that the parent rows are duplicated in the SQL query result set for each child record.

The `computeIfAbsent` method allows us to create a `PostDTO` object only if there is no existing `PostDTO` reference already stored in the `postDTOMap`.

The `PostDTO` class has a constructor that can set the `id` and `title` properties using the dedicated column aliases:

```
public class PostDTO {

    public static final String ID_ALIAS = "p_id";
    
    public static final String TITLE_ALIAS = "p_title";

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private List<PostCommentDTO> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public PostDTO(
            Object[] tuples, 
            Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap) {
            
        this.id = longValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(ID_ALIAS)]);
        this.title = stringValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(TITLE_ALIAS)]);
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `PostCommentDTO` is built in a similar fashion:

```
public class PostCommentDTO {

    public static final String ID_ALIAS = "pc_id";
    
    public static final String REVIEW_ALIAS = "pc_review";

    private Long id;

    private String review;

    public PostCommentDTO(
            Object[] tuples, 
            Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap) {
        this.id = longValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(ID_ALIAS)]);
        this.review = stringValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(REVIEW_ALIAS)]);
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

That's it!

Using the `PostDTOResultTransformer`, the SQL result set can be transformed into a hierarchical DTO projection, which is much convenient to work with, especially if it needs to be marshalled as a JSON response:

```
postDTOs = {ArrayList}, size = 2
  0 = {PostDTO} 
    id = 1L
    title = "High-Performance Java Persistence"
    comments = {ArrayList}, size = 2
      0 = {PostCommentDTO} 
        id = 1L
        review = "Best book on JPA and Hibernate!"
      1 = {PostCommentDTO} 
        id = 2L
        review = "A must read for every Java developer!"
  1 = {PostDTO} 
    id = 2L
    title = "Hypersistence Optimizer"
    comments = {ArrayList}, size = 1
      0 = {PostCommentDTO} 
       id = 3L
       review = "It's like pair programming with Vlad!"
```

Comment: That is the most obtrusive thats it I've seen in a long time.

Comment: @mjs Looking forward to seeing your answer to this question that provides us with a better solution. You do have a better alternative, don't you?